# Authentic Jenkins to Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have the latest 1.6.4 Kubernetes installed on my GCP cluster but cannot figure out how to give Jenkins authorization.

i just tried adding two new commands in jenkins file

sh(“gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-b”)

sh(“gcloud container clusters get-credentials te-cluster”)

1st was successful
second one failed

ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

Answer (score 0):

First create credentials using following: 
Navigate to **Google Cloud API Manager** > **Credentials** > **Create Credentials** and create a JSON key for the Compute Engine default service account.

Then use `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file key.json`

You can save the content of the json file to a variable